# In a loop, pass as argument to `redo` to change the current iteration's element

Tags: ruby

I have heard that it is not possible to modify an array while looping over it. But I wanted to post here to check that I'm not missing some trick or something.

Let me just give a little code to explain. This method is supposed to take an array of "ingredients" which are slices of bread, and then make two changes: toast the bread, then add butter.

```
ingredients = ["bread", "toast"]
buttered_slices = ingredients.map do |ingredient|
  if ingredient.eql?("toast")
    next "buttered_toast"
  else
    # ideally the ingredient variable would be "toast"
    # for the next iteration
    redo "toast"
  end
end
```

To be clear, this doesn't work. The `redo` doesn't care about the argument that it's given and the code enters an infinite loop.

*I've edited this question a bit to make the code more concise and less pseudocode-like. I also changed the title to be more specific*

Comment: Despite your example, I don't understand what the code is supposed to do. What is `to_buttered_toast` and `to_toast` (what do they do / return)? Why do you have to check the ingredient's type (what other classes are there)? Why are you trying to perform two separate actions at once? Maybe it would help to add some rudimentary classes (i.e. `Toast` and another "ingredient" class) along with an input array and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the approach provided by @Albin, one might achieve the same functionality with `redo`. You wrote “ideally "ingredient" would be ‘toast’ for the redo”— just do it;

```
buttered_slices = ingredients.map do |ingredient|
  if ingredient.is_a?(Toast)
    next ingredient.to_buttered_toast
  else
    ingredient = ingredient.to_toast
    redo
  end
end
```

As by documentation, [`redo`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-redo) preserves bindings, including bindings of local variables.

Frankly, I do not get what is the reason of so cumbersome approach:

```
buttered_slices = ingredients.map do |ingredient|
  (ingredient.is_a?(Toast) ? ingredient : ingredient.to_toast).to_buttered_toast
end
```

Comment: `redo` is a keyword, not a method.

Comment: @cremno thanks for mentioning this. I was curious if there was a way to overwrite it. Also not sure how I could write a wrapper method for `redo`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not solve it like this:

```
def turn_each_ingredient_into_buttered_toast(ingredients)
  ingredients.map do |ingredient|
    unless ingredient.is_a?(Toast)
      ingredient = ingredient.to_toast
    end
    ingredient.to_buttered_toast
  end
end
```

You do not actually redo the iteration but you achieve the same result.

Also worth noting is that the assignment to `buttered_slices` is unnecessary as well as the `next` call.